# Integrating factor, initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having trouble starting this problem. I need help on determining the integrating factor by first setting up in standard form...

$y' + p(x)y = f(x) $

Solve for IVP.

> $$yy' + 3t^2 - 2 = 0$$
>   $$y(-1) = 2$$

Seeing the "$yy'$" together is throwing me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$yy'+3t^{ 2 }-2=0\\ { \left( { y }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ \prime  }=4-6{ t }^{ 2 }\\ { y }^{ 2 }=4t-2{ t }^{ 3 }+C$$
 as we are given $\\ y(-1)=2$ so $$4=-4+2+C\quad \\ C=6$$

> $${ y }^{ 2 }=4t-2{ t }^{ 3 }+6
> $$

Comment: From the first step to the second step, How did you know to multiply by 2? Is it because it's what is given in $y(-1) = 2$?

Comment: no, because of ${ \left( { y }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ \prime  }=2yy'$